# React.Почему не фильтрует массив? В handleDelete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Если выводит id элемента то все верно, map который выше работает, но filter нет, в чем проблема?[image: Пример]

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./scss/style.scss";
import todosArray from "./todosArray"
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Todo from "./components/Todo";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: todosArray};
        this.handleStatusChange = this.handleStatusChange.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }

    handleStatusChange(id) {
       let resultList =  todosArray.map(todo => {
            if (todo.id === id) {
                todo.completed = !todo.completed;
            }
            return todo;
        });
        this.setState({items: resultList});
    }

    handleDelete(id) {
        console.log(id);
        let resultList = todosArray.filter(todo =>todo.id !== id);
        this.setState({items: resultList});
        console.log(resultList)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <Header title={this.props.title}/>
                <section className="todo-list">
                    {
                        this.state.items.map(todo =>
                            < Todo
                                key={todo.id}
                                id={todo.id}
                                title={todo.title}
                                completed={todo.completed}
                                onStatusChange={this.handleStatusChange}
                                onDelete={this.handleDelete}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                </section>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

const todosArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Изучить JavaScript c Николаем",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Изучить React",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Написать приложение",
    completed: false
  }
];

export default todosArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Метод filter() **создаёт новый массив** со всеми элементами, прошедшими проверку, задаваемую в передаваемой функции. [дока](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

В вашей функции результат фильтрации ничему не присваивается, а в `setState` передается исходный "нефильтрованный" массив.

UPDATE по результатам комментариев:

Кроме указанной выше ошибки вы пытаетесь работать не со стейтом, а с константой, содержащей массив. Соответственно ничего не меняется.

Сделал рабочий пример

```js
const todosArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Изучить JavaScript c Николаем",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Изучить React",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Написать приложение",
    completed: false
  }
];

class Todo extends React.Component {
  onStatusChange = () => {
    this.props.onStatusChange(this.props.id);
  };

  onDelete = () => {
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.id);
  };

  render() {
    return (
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          {this.props.completed &&
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"/>
          }
          {this.props.title}
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-right">
        <button 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.onStatusChange}
        >Завершить</button>
        {' '}
        <button 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-danger"
          onClick={this.onDelete}
        >Удалить</button>
      </div>
    </div>);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
          items: todosArray
        };
        this.handleStatusChange = this.handleStatusChange.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }

    handleStatusChange(id) {
       let resultList =  this.state.items.map(todo => {
         if (todo.id === id) {
           todo.completed = !todo.completed;
         }
         return todo;
       });
       this.setState({items: resultList});
    }

    handleDelete(id) {
        console.log(id);
        let resultList = this.state.items.filter(todo =>todo.id !== id);
        this.setState({items: resultList});
        console.log(resultList)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <section className="todo-list">
                    {
                        this.state.items.map(todo =>
                            <Todo
                                key={todo.id}
                                id={todo.id}
                                title={todo.title}
                                completed={todo.completed}
                                onStatusChange={this.handleStatusChange}
                                onDelete={this.handleDelete}
                            />
                        )
                    }
                </section>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: сделал как сказал, ничего не получилось(

Comment: вы "пихаете" в стейт весь массив в `handleStatusChange`. `setState` не переписывает массив, он обновляет содержимое новыми данными. Поскольку в стейте уже есть все элементы, то `setState({фильтрованный массив})` просто обновляет элементы, попавшие в фильтр. Старые никуда не деваются и все выглядит как будто фильтр не сработал. Заведите в стейте ключ `items` и присваивайте массив ему. `setState({items: нефильрованный массив})`, `setState({items: фильтрованный массив})`. Тогда объект в стейте будет перезаписан новыми значениями

Comment: Я просто еще новичок в реакт,  в стейте ключ items это т е в constructore?А потом в обоих функциях его менять или как?

Comment: Я поменял код, можешь глянуть?

Comment: В рендере, как я понимаю, вместо `this.todosArray.map(todo =>` должно быть `this.state.items.map(todo =>`

Comment: в конструкторе вместо `this.todosArray = todosArray;` надо `this.state = {items: todosArray};`

Comment: Вроде все сделал, но появилась багулина, если удаляешь 1 айтем он пропадает, нажимаешь на 2 он исчезает и появляется тот который был удален, т е их всегда 2 , нажимаешь на handleDelete появляется 3

Comment: Дополнил ответ и дал рабочий пример